# Spring boot Job using delay not to work fine

Tags: java, spring, delay, scheduler, jobs

I've defined 3 jobs using fixedDelayString=300000 (5 minutes) and I did that 3 these jobs will be executed independently. For that reason, I created an Async implementation. At first, each job worked fine, but in the time they started to delay a lot.
Each execution is about 5seg, but the next execution started to run after 10minutes. And occasionally 15 or 18minutes.

An example could be:

```
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
  @Async('threadPoolTaskExecutor')
  @Scheduled(fixedDelayString=15000)
  public void doSomething1() {
    // something that should run periodically
  }

  @Async('threadPoolTaskExecutor')
  @Scheduled(fixedDelayString=300000)
  public void doSomething2() {
    // something that should run periodically
  }

  @Async('threadPoolTaskExecutor')
  @Scheduled(fixedDelayString=300000)
  public void doSomething3() {
    // this job begins to have interval larger in each execution
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConf {
  @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
  public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
      ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
      executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
      executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
      executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
      return executor;
  }
}
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

To mention the fixed delay, it should be `fixedDelay` instead of `fixedDelayString`. Check below code:

```
@Async('threadPoolTaskExecutor')
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000)
public void doSomething3() { ... }
```

Also you should write `@EnableScheduling` annotation on your configuration class.

Also note that `fixedDelay` specifies that job should run next after specified amount of time once execution is completed. If you want to run your jobs at fixed intervals, you should try `fixedRate` instead of `fixedDelay`. Check more about scheduling here - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks